# Clearcase error adding file

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I cannot add a new file to the VOB. I tried both UI context menu on windows as well as cleartool command line utility.

```
cleartool> checkout .
Checkout comments for ".":
Created branch "BRANCH_NAME" from "." version "\main\BASE_BRANCH_NAME\1".
Checked out "." from version "\main\BASE_BRANCH_NAME\BRANCH_NAME\0".
cleartool> mkelem -ci -nc NewFile.h
Created element "NewFile.h" (type "text_file").
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "NewFile.h".
cleartool> uncheckout .
```

describe -l . shows me that the folder has rwx permissions. What am I doing wrong? Why I can't add file?

Comment: your config spec probably doesn't have `element * CHECKEDOUT` at the top?  Or you have no `element * /main/LATEST` or similar catch-all rule.

Comment: No, in fact I do have `element * CHECKEDOUT` at the top of the configspec.

Comment: Please reproduce your entire config spec here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014091473) (and already commented):

> You'll need a rule that selects `/main/0` or `/main/LATEST`

`/main/0` is the **[placeholder version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309714/6309)** created for any new element added to source control.
See for instance "[how to create a branch in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110226/6309)" or "[How best to branch in Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/997607/6309)" for an example of a config spec allowing to add to source control in a branch.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * .../aBranch/LATEST  
element * STARTING_LABEL -mkbranch aBranch 
# selection rule for new "added to source control" file
element * /main/0 -mkbranch aBranch 
element * /main/LATEST
```